# Laravel 8 component button "onclick" directly activating on load not on click

Tags: php, html, laravel-8

I'm using a component with a public function **UnlockAdvertisement(int $id)**
In this component I have a button with the onclick function used.
But this function gets triggered everytime the component gets loaded, not when the button gets clicked.
It's like reversed?!

Thanks ahead for your help

The component is used via a yield

```php
@section('advertisementView')
    <div class="container">
        <x-advertisement.advertisement-view-master :id="$id"/>
        @yield('advertisementViewForUnlock')
    </div>
@endsection
```

This is the component in the yielded blade:

```php
@extends('Advertisements.AdvertisementView')

@section('advertisementViewForUnlock')
<div class="container">
    <x-management.unlock-advertisement :id="$id"/>
</div>
@endsection
```

and this is the actual component

```php
<div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success me-1"
                    onclick=" {{ $UnlockAdvertisement($AdvertisementId) }}">Freischalten</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Ablehnen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function that gets executed at site load not at button click

```php
    public function UnlockAdvertisement(int $id)
    {
        $tempAdvertisement = Advertisement::where('id', $id)->first();
        $tempAdvertisement->unlocked = true;
        $tempAdvertisement->save();

        return redirect()->route('management-dashboard');
    }
```